# The argument type 'void Function({required String? value})' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'void Function(String?)?'

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a function called `onServerChanged`. This was working fine when I did the below:

```
void onServerChanged(String? value) {
    //...
}

DropdownButton<String>(
  //...
  onChanged: onServerChanged,
),
```

However, when I changed the function to this, it stopped working:

```
void onServerChanged({required String? value}) {
    //...
}
```

This gives an error pointing the function call in the `DropdownButton`:

> The argument type 'void Function({required String? value})' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'void Function(String?)?'

I really like forcing myself to write the parameter name whenever I call a function so that refactoring doesn't create silent errors. I tried adding the parameter to the function call in the `DropdownButton` but it didn't work. How would I fix this so I can still use named parameters here?

Comment: how would you like to use a named parameter with `onServerChanged` in: `onChanged: onServerChanged`? it is simply impossible - `onChanged` takes a single `String?` parameter function so you have to create your `onSrverChanged` the same way

Comment: `onChanged` use positional argument, it is not possible using name parameter directly like this but you can wrap with another function.

Comment: @pskink if I'm forced to use a positional argument and there is no other way around it, then it is what it is. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing your function signature to use a named parameter instead of a positional one causes the `DropdownButton` to call it incorrectly, since internally it's doing `onChanged.call(value)`, whereas your signature would require `onChanged.call(value: value)`.

You can easily fix this by slightly adjusting how you handle the callback. Try something like this:

```dart
void onServerChanged({required String? value}) {
    //...
}

DropdownButton<String>(
  //...
  onChanged: (value) => onServerChanged(value: value),
),
```

Now, you're passing a callback that takes a positional value. That callback then calls your `onServerChanged` function with a named parameter, and everyone's happy.